# im4java compare command giving Command exception

Tags: im4java

Following code gives **org.im4java.core.CommandException: org.im4java.core.CommandException: return code: 1**     I am trying to compare two colors. what is wrong in my code or what is the correct solution to compare colors.

```
    ImageCommand compare=new ImageCommand();
    compare.setCommand("compare");
    IMOperation op = new IMOperation();
    op.fuzz(30.0);
    op.metric("AE");
    op.addImage();
    op.addImage();
    op.addImage();

    compare.run(op,"xc:green","xc:brown","null:");
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because ImageMagick's `compare` will return [a non-zero exit code if the images are dissimilar](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/compare.php). But the comparison should be working, the resulting difference image (3rd argument) is correctly generated.

It's however a problem for `im4java` because that's considered an error exit code, and there's no way as far as I know to tell `im4java` that it's not. See [this discussion](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=22451) for more details.

You can work around it by catching the exception and ignoring it if the return code was 1 (`compare` should return `2` in case of error).